# How can I sum the integers of a column in this 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

The following code calculate the sum of each row of 'int[,] a'. What I want is to modify it so it calculates the sum per column; 1+1+1, 2+2+2, 3+3+3, 4+4+4 instead of per row. These values will be put inside 'int[] output'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4},
                        { 1, 2, 3, 4} };

            int[] b = SumColumn(a);
        }

 public static int[] SumColumn(int[,] a)
        {
            int[] output = new int[a.GetLength(1)];
            int sum = 0;
      
            for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    sum += a[i, j];
                }

                output[i] = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
            return output;
        }
```

So i tried adding a counter and using a boolean in the nested loop (and otther methods), however it did not work for me.

Comment: You got the answer already but you should definitely try debugging this code yourself and see that you mixed up iterating over the dimensions. Its an essential thing knowing how to debug something.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to move `.GetLength` outside the loop, since this is a comparatively slow operation. That won't matter in this case, but it might if you start using much larger arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is *almost* identical in both cases. Only the loops get flipped

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] a = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4},
                    { 1, 2, 3, 4} };

        int[] rowSums = RowSums(a);
        int[] colSums = ColumnSums(a);

        Console.WriteLine($"Row Sums: {string.Join(",", rowSums)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Col Sums: {string.Join(",", colSums)}");
    }

    public static int[] ColumnSums(int[,] matrix)
    {
        int rowCount = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int colCount = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int[] result = new int[colCount];
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                sum += matrix[i, j];
            }
            result[j] = sum;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int[] RowSums(int[,] matrix)
    {
        int rowCount = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int colCount = matrix.GetLength(1);

        int[] result = new int[rowCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
                sum += matrix[i, j];
            }
            result[i] = sum;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

PS. In your code there is no need to set `sum=0;` in the end of the outer loop, as it will get set to zero in the beginning of the next loop.

The output should be

```text
Row Sums: 10,10,10
Col Sums: 3,6,9,12
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap `i` and `j` loops so you will iterate through columns first and then iterate for each row's j-th element in the column:

```
public static int[] SumColumn(int[,] a)
{
    int[] output = new int[a.GetLength(1)];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            sum += a[i, j];
        }

        output[j] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    return output;
}
```

This function initializes the `output` array with length equal to the **number of columns** in the input array. Then it declares an integer variable `sum` to accumulate a result for column.

Then we use two nested for loops to iterate over the rows and columns but use `j` and `GetLength(1)` in the outer loop to iterate via each column and `i` and `GetLength(1)` in the inner loop to iterate for each `j`-th element for all rows. Each iteration of the inner loop add value of the current cell to the `sum`.

After summarizing values in all rows we add the `sum` to the current index of the `output` and reset it for using in the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public static int[] SumColumn(int[,] array) {
  // Do not forget to validate public method arguments
  if (array is null)
    return null;

  // result is an array (an item for each column)
  // Note, that result will be filled by 0, so we don't have to use sum variable
  int[] result = new int[array.GetLength(1)];

  // For each column col
  for (int col = 0; col < result.Length; ++col) 
    for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); ++row) // ... we sum rows
      result[col] += array[row][col];

  return result; 
}
```